# C# GUI WinFormsApp textbox and trackbar values not saving or updating

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview, textbox

so I am new to C# and am trying to create a really basic GUI on Visual Studio using `WinFormsApp` and the `Designer`.

Basically in my GUI there is a textbox that asks for a movie title and then a trackbar that asks you for a rating (picture below). What I want to do is save both the `textbox.Text` and `trackbar.Value` to variables, then put them into a `datagridview`.

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public int count = 0;
    public string rating = "default";
    public string movie_title = "default";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        movie_title = textBox1.Text;
        return movie_title;
    }

    public string trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rating = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
        return rating;
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] newrow = { movie_title, rating };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newrow);
    }

}
}
```

When I run this code the form appears but when I put text in the `textbox` and move the `trackbar` button around and press the button, a new row is added but it reads "default" in both the title and rating, which is how I initialized the variable, so it isn't properly updating.

[Here's what that looks like when it runs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzPPh.png)

Any ideas? Thanks for the help, am trying to learn sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Event Handlers don't return a value (as in `public string trackBar1_ValueChanged()`), hence you have modified those methods or added them manually, but these are not actually handling the events (they cannot, since the signature doesn't match the delegate's). Did you set a breakpoint in those methods, to check if/when they're called? -- In your view, e.g., `return movie_title;` what would that return a value to?

Answer (score 0):

As Jimi notes the events you show are not getting fired and because of this `movie_title` and `rating` are never set outside their initial settings of  `public string rating = "default";` … and `public string movie_title = "default";`.

I suggest you completely DROP these events. In other words, even if the user “changes” a movie or sets a rating, then, the user has NOT YET clicked the button. It seems unnecessary to “collect” the `movie_title` or the `rating` BEFORE the user has clicked the button.

Drop those events and simply grab those values in the button click event. Something like…

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] newrow = { textBox1.Text, trackBar1.Value.ToString() };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newrow);
}
```

OR

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, trackBar1.Value.ToString());
}
```

Lastly, I highly encourage you to use a `DataSource` for the grid. Manually adding the rows to the grid as the code does… only “creates” MORE work for you. If you used a `DataSource` to the grid, then in the button click event, you would add the data to the grids `DataSource` as opposed to setting it into the grid directly. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful! Everytime I click on a control it automatically adds those events and when I try to remove them it creates an error in the Designer, I will look into how to do that. Also, I have heard about DataSource I just didn't know how to use it or create the source, so I'll look into that too. Thanks!

Comment: @arv24_ …It may be true that … _”Everytime I click on a control it automatically adds those events”_ … BUT… YOU or someone else has “altered/changed” those method signatures that were automatically created, thus rendering them unusable and most likely is causing some compiler errors in the `Designer.cs` file. You do NOT want to alter the signature of the methods that are “automatically” created when you double click a control. This is what Jimi’s comment is all about.

Comment: @arv24_ … In your particular case the `textBox1_TextChanged` event is “returning” a `string` and events typically DO NOT return anything and the signature would normally look like…  `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` … You or someone has “changed” this and the track bar event in the same fashion. Both should have a `void` return value and not a `string` and the events should not be `return`ing anything.